# Jquery UI Draggable: div not resizing on top and left side

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

As you can see here http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ dragging the draggable item to the right or bottom side of the container div make it extending but that doesn't happen when dragging the draggable iem to the top or left side: is possible to solve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would involve you changing the scroll bar. I would use jScrollPane at this [link](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) then apply the jQuery UI